# Draw horizontal line left and right of some text (a single line)

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want a horizontal line to the left and right of some text, that is at most one line wide. The lines should be equally sized such that they fill the remaining horizontal space (like two `\hfill`s in a `\hbox`).

In case it's not clear what I want, at the top of this page there is a row of buttons labeled **Questions | Tags | Users | Badges | Unanswered**. And above that row of buttons are two horizontal lines filling the remaining space around a symbol. That is what I want to accomplish in LaTeX.

Comment: Ok, and how should the text be placed? Centered?

Comment: Yes, the text should be centered.

Comment: Should the line be at the baseline (where the uppercase letters sit on) or vertically centered?

Comment: @Martin: vertically centered would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add the lines using `\hrulefill` and create the line using `\makebox[\linewidth]`. The vertical alignment is a little tricky. I don't know how to raise the filler, so one way is to lower the text first and than raise it again with the lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\hrulefill}}}

\begin{document}

\hrule
Before\\
\ruleline{TestXg}
After

\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to center the lines vertically? I suppose that centering on the height of the lower case letters would look the best.

Comment: @Mike: I just added that. I'm using .8ex as height. 1ex would be the height of a lower case 'x'. An upper case 'X' is about 1.6ex, so .8ex seemed to be a good value.

Comment: The resulting line is shifted to the right on a right page by ~1cm.

Comment: @Mike: Might be the paragraph indent. Place a `\noindent` before it or at the beginning of the macro (maybe with a leading `\par`).

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\def\headline#1{\hbox to \hsize{\hrulefill\quad\lower.3em\hbox{#1}\quad\hrulefill}}

\begin{document}    
\headline{Centered \ddag{} Symbol} 
\end{document}
```

[image: headline macro example]

Admittedly, this is a TeX solution but I think it is appropriate because this is where TeX is really great. If you need some vertical space after the headline you could incorporate a `\medskip` right before the last closing brace of the `\headline` definition. And on second thought: the `.3em` dimension should be better expressed using `ex`.