# Line on the left and right of sections names

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I'd like to have lines on the right and left of every section name. Kind of like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15119/draw-horizontal-line-left-and-right-of-some-text-a-single-line) but instead of having just a bit of text and adding lines to fill the textwidth, I'd like to have the section name stay where it is but have lines in the margin, and if possible also fill the remaining space.

```
margin              text                   margin
<-----> <-------------------------------> <------>

        I'd like it to look like this:

------- 1 - This section                  --------

        Normal text is from here to there
        and then it gets on a new line.

        Or (even better) like that:

------- 2 - That section -------------------------

        Normal text is from here to there
        and then it gets on a new line.
```

I tried using the code from the linked question but apparently, the text from sections is magical and you can't put it in either of their solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, you will always need to use the optional short section name (toc) with this approach.  You can always define a `\mysection` to take care of both.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linetitle}[1]% #1 = section title text
{\settowidth{\@tempdimb}{\@svsec}% section number is variable width
 \llap{\rule{\marginparwidth}{1pt}\hspace{\marginparsep}\hspace{\@tempdimb}}% left margin
 \parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\@tempdimb}{#1}%
 \rlap{\hspace{\marginparsep}\rule{\marginparwidth}{1pt}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section[Section Name]{\linetitle{Section Name}}
\setcounter{section}{21}
\section[Test]{\linetitle{\blindtext}}
\end{document}
```

[image: full page]