# How to manage rectangles and lengths with TikZ package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, diagrams, line-spacing, lengths

I have been customizing a CV template but having some trouble with the TikZ package; indeed I'm a novice and it's a little bit difficult for me to find the solution by using the official documentation.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}

%%% PREAMBLE %%%
% Info
\title{My CV}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=0.5cm,  % left=0.1cm
    right=0.5cm, % right=0.6cm
    top=0.5cm,   % top=0.1cm
    bottom=1.0cm, % bottom=0.1cm
    includefoot,
    headheight=2.5cm, % needed to avoid warnings with fancyhdr package
    footskip=0.4cm,
    showframe=false
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{adjustbox} % to a better alignement of text

% Headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\setlength{\headheight}{12.6pt}
\usepackage{lastpage}

% Text and Fonts
\usepackage[TU]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand{\MATLAB}{\textsc{MATLAB}\xspace}
%\usepackage{microtype} %it helps to fit text inside margins)
\usepackage[en-AU]{datetime2}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Tables
\usepackage{multirow}

% to have awesome icon 
%\usepackage{fontawesome} 
\usepackage{fontawesome5} 
\usepackage{academicons}

% advanced drawing
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} 
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar} 
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{topaths}
\usepackage{graphicx}


% set TikZ styles
\tikzset{
  contactIcon/.style={%
    minimum height=\baselineskip,
  }
}

% pictures
\usepackage{graphicx}
% loads graphicx, provides align=c option for vertical alignment w.r.t. text
\RequirePackage{graphbox}

\newcommand{\roundpic}[1]{\begin{figure}[H]\tikz  \draw [path picture={ \node at (path picture bounding box.center){\includegraphics[height=3cm]{#1}} ;}] (0,2) circle (1.7) ;\end{figure}}

% more advanced expressions in \setlength
\usepackage{calc}

% Define Colors
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{titleBackColor}{RGB}{25,20,60} %original color: {rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}
\definecolor{sideBarColor}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{mydarkblue}{rgb}{0.07,0.08,0.4}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.4,.4,1}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{245,169,34}

% links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=black}

% Lists
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=0pt,leftmargin=*,nosep}
%\setlist{leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,nosep,itemsep=0.15\baselineskip,after=\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}}

% Define Lengths
\setlength\parindent{0.0cm}
\newlength\cvPictureWidth    \setlength\cvPictureWidth{4cm}
\newlength\SidebarWidth      \setlength\SidebarWidth{7.5cm} %8cm
\newlength\leftSideSecWidth  \setlength\leftSideSecWidth{2.5cm} %2cm
\newlength\rightSideSecWidth \setlength\rightSideSecWidth{9cm} %9cm
\newlength\SecHorizSpace     \setlength\SecHorizSpace{0.1cm}
\newlength\SecVertSpace      \setlength\SecVertSpace{0.4cm}
\newlength\rightMinipageWidth \setlength\rightMinipageWidth{12cm}%11.8cm
\newlength\leftMinipageWidth \setlength\leftMinipageWidth{6.5cm}%7cm

% avoid line overflow
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{2pt}

%------------ font highlighting / boxes with background color 
\newcommand{\bg}[3]{\colorbox{#1}{\bfseries\color{#2}#3}}
\newcommand{\bgupper}[3]{\colorbox{#1}{\color{#2}\huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#3}}}
%%% NEW HEADER
\newcommand{\header}[7]{%Inputs: #1 = up rectangle color, #2= up rectangle text, #3 = central rectangle color, #4= fig.name, #5= backgr. rect. col. , #6= fig horizontal pos., #7= text horiz. pos.
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
\node[rectangle, fill=#1, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=5cm](header) at (current page.north){};% background rectangle
\node[left=#2 of header.north, anchor=east](name) at (header.east){\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\selectfont #3};%
\node[anchor=south west](degree) at (name.north west){\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\selectfont #4};%
\node[anchor=north west](descr) at (name.south west) {\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\selectfont #5};%
\node[right=#6 of header.west, anchor=west](picture) at (header.west) {};%
\draw[draw=myyellow, line width=0.3mm,path picture={\node[anchor=center] at (path picture bounding box.center){\includegraphics[width=4.0cm]{#7}} ;}] (picture) circle (2cm) ;}%
\vspace{1.5cm}%
}

%%%%%%%

% SideBar
\newcommand{\sidebar}[1]{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
\node[rectangle, fill=#1, anchor=north west, minimum width=\SidebarWidth, minimum height=\paperheight](header) at (current page.north west){};%current page (text area).north west, height= \textheight
}
} %original: minimum width=8.6cm

\newcommand{\MySectionTitle}[2]{% max 9 parameters !
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]% '%' are vital in macros! (dangling space issues)
        % \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (5,-2);%    

        \node[font = {\Large},circle,fill=myyellow, minimum size = 1.2cm]%
            (c) at (0.5,-1){#1};% <<< NEW   
        \draw[orange, thick] (c.0) -- (\textwidth,-1); % <<< NEW (Q3)
        \node at (6.8,-.8) [align=left,text width=8cm]  { \bf \Large \color{titleBackColor}\MakeUppercase{#2}};%\MakeUppercase{#2}};% <<< (Q2) almost    
    \end{tikzpicture}%
       
    \vspace{1.5cm}% !!! the next empty line is needed: else the layout breaks

}
% ~~~ Command for Education and Works ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\MySection}[7]{% input: #1=title, #2=years, #3=logo, #4=university, #5=city, #6=specialization, #7=description
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\leftSideSecWidth}%
        \begin{flushleft}% 
            \vspace*{0.1cm}
            {\footnotesize\bfseries \uppercase{#1}}\\%title
            {\scriptsize #2}\\% years   
            \vspace*{0.1cm}
            \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=1.2cm]{#3} %logo
        \end{flushleft}%
    \end{minipage}}}%
    \hspace{\SecHorizSpace} \hfill%\vline %\hfill
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{9.0cm}%
        {\small\bfseries \textsc{#4}}%university
        \hfill {\footnotesize \faMapMarker  ~ #5}% city
        \newline%
        \small {#6}% specialization        
        \footnotesize {#7}% description
    \end{minipage}}%
    \vspace*{\SecVertSpace}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Format of the title section in the side column
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65731
\makeatletter
\def\cv@hrulefill{{\color{titleBackColor}\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1pt\hfill\kern\z@}}
% line before and after text (some tweaking is required here)
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15119
\NewDocumentCommand{\ruleline}{m}{\par\noindent\raisebox{\baselineskip/4}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\cv@hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-\baselineskip/4}{\large #1}\hspace{1ex}\cv@hrulefill}}\vspace*{0.05cm}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows creating custom \sections

% Format of the section titles
\titleformat{\section}{
\bf \Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % smallcaps, Large, continuous line - looks better if two columns, might look a bit too dramatic if just one ;) 
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt}{5pt} % Spacing around titles {<left spacing>}{<before spacing>}{<after spacing>}

% Multiple Column Package
\usepackage{multicol}

% Generate QR Code from a link
\usepackage{qrcode}

% pictoFraction
\newcommand{\icon}[3]{\phantom{x}{#3\color{#2}#1}\phantom{x}}
%------------------- pictogram Fraction: pictoFraction
\newcommand{\pictofraction}[6]{%
\pgfmathparse{#3 - 1}\foreach \n in {0,...,\pgfmathresult}{\icon{#1}{#2}{#6}}%
\pgfmathparse{#5 - 1}\foreach \n in {0,...,\pgfmathresult}{\icon{#1}{#4}{#6}}%
}
%%% END PREAMBLE %%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\overfullrule=0.2cm % 
\begin{document}


%%% Footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small \textcolor{black}{\footnotesize I hereby authorize the processing of the personal data contained in this CV in compliance with the European Regulation (UE) 2016/679.\\[0.2cm]
\footnotesize  Page \textcolor{black}{\thepage} of  \pageref*{LastPage}}}
% \fancyfoot[C]{\small  \textcolor{black}{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of  \pageref{LastPage}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Side bar
\sidebar{sideBarColor!25}

% \simpleheader{titleBackColor}{white}{Giuseppe Donnarumma}{Aerospace Engineer}{shuttle.pdf}

\header{titleBackColor}{6cm}{\bgupper{titleBackColor}{white}{\bfseries\huge XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX}}{\bg{titleBackColor}{white}{Aerospace engineer} }{\bg{titleBackColor}{myyellow}{\large Curriculum Vitae}}{2.5cm}{example-image-a}

% Start Minipages
\vspace*{3.0cm}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\leftMinipageWidth}     
        
    % Profile section
    \ruleline{\textbf{About me}}
    \lipsum[11]
    \vspace*{0.2cm}
    
    \lipsum[2]

    % QR Code
    \begin{flushright}
    \small \textbf{\aiOverleaf Download my CV}\\
   
   \footnotesize Last updated: \today \\
    \vspace*{0.2cm}
       % \quad
        \bg{white}{black}{\qrcode[height=2.0cm]{}} \\       
    \end{flushright}                   
\end{minipage}}} %
     \hfill 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% MAIN SECTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\rightMinipageWidth} %11.3cm       
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Work Experience
    \MySectionTitle{\faSuitcase}{work experiences}

    % input: #1=title, #2=years, #3=logo, #4=university, #5=city, #6=specialization, #7=description
    \MySection{Visiting Researcher}
            {Feb.--Mar. 20XX}
            {example-image-b}            
            {University}
            {Rome, Italy}
            {Aerospace Engineering}
            {\newline \lipsum[11]}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \MySectionTitle{\faGraduationCap}{Education}

    \MySection{Master's Degree}
    {20XX--20XX}
    {example-image-c}
    {University xxxxxxxx}
    {Rome, Italy}
    {Aerospace Engineering}
    {\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,label=\textcolor{titleBackColor}{\textbullet}]
        \item Thesis title
        \item Thesis subject
        \item Thesis keywords 
        \item Graduation grade
    \end{itemize}   
    }
        
    \MySection{Bachelor's Degree}{20xx--20xx}{example-image-c}{University xxxxxx}{xxxxxx, Italy}{Aerospace Engineering}{\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,label=\textcolor{titleBackColor}{\textbullet}]
        \item Thesis title
        \item Thesis subject
        \item Graduation grade
    \end{itemize}
    }
   
    \MySection{High School Diploma}{20xx--20xx}{example-image-c}{IIS \enquote{xxxxxxxx}}{XXXXXXX, Italy}{Liceo Scientifico}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Kind of secondary school: Italian secondary school
        \item Diploma grade
    \end{itemize} 
    }
    
    \vspace*{\SecVertSpace}
        
\end{minipage}} 
}%
\end{document}
```

I'd like to solve the following points (see the next image for better understanding):

1. Move the QR code and the above sentences (see elements inside the bounded area 1) to the header of my CV;
2. Modify the coloured sidebar width and the image position such as the segments (2) are all equal;
3. Decrease the line spacing (3) in the boxes of the sections to make them more compact;
4. Colour the footer background.

I apologize for asking many requests in a unique question. If it is required, I can split in different questions.

[image: my CV]

Answer (score 2):

Your code became quite complex since last time, containing packages which don't seem to be used here. Looks like you've got lost on your way?

I suggest taking ***a more layout based approach*** using package `flowfram`. This takes away a lot of burden, conventional LaTeX finetuning imposes. However, it may require some learning.

So please find attached ***a framework you can build upon***, e.g. by adding your fonts, colors, macros as needed. The layout part tends to be a bit more complicated, while the textual content becomes easy again. // You probably can reuse relevant parts of your code with little to no change, while getting rid of complex intertanglements.

In consequence, and that's a plus, you can focus on answering the question for each frame individually "how would I code only this part in an article-based document?" (e.g. text-part in header as a very short standalone document)

**By intention this layout only works for page 1, see below, and runs with pdflatex.**

So let's have a look. Steps 1 and 2 define the paper geometry and colors. The relevant part comes with step 3:

- you can switch on and off flowfram's `draft` option, see also right image below
- the content (your profile) will be placed in the one and only flowframe, which I placed conveniently to the right
- from here on I use only static frames
- the sidebar comes in two flavors:
- a) an oversized one for the background color
- b) just a textframe, conveniently resized a little
- this idea is repeated for the header and the simpler footer
- the header has also 3 frames, one each for image (hdi), text (hdt) and QR (hdq), so you can shift them around easily as needed
- by adding `[1]` to the commands, all frames will only appear on said page, which is 1; see manual for details

```
% ~~~ 3. frames, all limited to page 1 via [1] ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[
%   draft
    ]{flowfram}

%     3a. content       W              H         x    y
\newflowframe[1]{\textwidth-75mm}{\textheight}{75mm}{0pt}

%     3b. sidebar
\newstaticframe*[1]{75mm}{\paperheight}{-5mm}{0pt}[sidefill]% oversized colored
\newstaticframe*[1]{65mm}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[side]% "text"-frame
...
```

The left image shows the result without, the right one with flowfram's `draft` option. To make it easier to follow I indicated the various static-frame-labels, and the reference point to the lower left of the paper.

[image: result]

Step 4 gives other packages needed to make this work. Step 5 are other needed macros, one for the sidebar headers appearance, one for the rounded picture in the header.

Now the content of this document, step 6.

Flowfram provides environements to put something inside the various static frames. The stared version is for labeled frames.

```
% ~~~ 6. THE CONTENT ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

% ~~~ header contents ~~~~~~~
\begin{staticcontents*}{hdi}% header image to the left
    \roundpic{example-image-a}
\end{staticcontents*}
...
```

Once you did all that, you only need to fill the white area, the one and only flowframe in this document. I.e. use regular LaTeX here again. Think and keep it simple. Try standard LaTeX first before turning to just another package (which may increase the chances for unwanted results).

**Finally**, you may need to turn on absolute pages when you add frames for page 2 etc. See flowfram's manual.

Flowfram's examples calculate lengths sometimes, which I hard-coded here. It's up to you to decide, which approach works better for you.

To realign e.g. header-items, adjust their frame parameters in the preamble. That's all you need to do to shift those items around.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% ~~~ 1. paper layout ~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=0.5cm,
    right=0.5cm,
    top=47mm,% <<< NEW
    bottom=1.0cm,
    includefoot,
    headheight=2.5cm, % needed to avoid warnings with fancyhdr package
    footskip=0.4cm,
%    showframe=true
}

\pagestyle{empty}   % disabling headers and footers
\parindent0pt       % no indent of first paragraph line

% ~~~ 2. colors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gry}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{gryf}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{blk}{gray}{0.}

% ~~~ 3. frames, all limited to page 1 via [1] ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[
%   draft
    ]{flowfram}

%     3a. content       W              H         x    y
\newflowframe[1]{\textwidth-75mm}{\textheight}{75mm}{0pt}

%     3b. sidebar
\newstaticframe*[1]{75mm}{\paperheight}{-5mm}{0pt}[sidefill]% oversized colored
\newstaticframe*[1]{65mm}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[side]% "text"-frame

%     3c. header and footer
\newstaticframe*[1]{\paperwidth}{47mm}{-5mm}{\paperheight -52mm}[hdfill]
\newstaticframe*[1]{50mm}{40mm}{0mm}{\paperheight -52mm}[hdi]%   header image
\newstaticframe*[1]{50mm}{40mm}{40mm}{\paperheight -52mm}[hdt]%  header text
\newstaticframe*[1]{50mm}{40mm}{185mm}{\paperheight -52mm}[hdq]% header QR
\newstaticframe*[1]{\paperwidth}{14mm}{-5mm}{-14mm}[ft]

% ~~~ 3d. filling frames with color ~~~~~~~~~~~
\setallstaticframes{border=none}
\setstaticframe*{sidefill}{backcolor=gry}
\setstaticframe*{side}{valign=t}
\setstaticframe*{hdfill}{backcolor=gryf}
\setstaticframe*{ft}{backcolor=gryf}

% ~~~ 4. other packages ~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

% ~~~ 5. other macros ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%     headers in the sidebar
\newcommand\sidehd[1]{\hrulefill\raisebox{-3pt}{\textbf{\hspace{.8em}#1\hspace{1em}}}\hrulefill\vspace{4pt}}% good old LaTeX adjustments

%     rounded picture in header
\newcommand{\roundpic}[1]{\tikz{\draw [path picture={ \node at (path picture bounding box.center){\includegraphics[height=30mm,scale=.7]{#1}} ;}] (0,0) circle (1.3) ;}}

% ~~~ 6. THE CONTENT ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

% ~~~ header contents ~~~~~~~
\begin{staticcontents*}{hdi}% header image to the left
    \roundpic{example-image-a}
\end{staticcontents*}
% ---------------------------
\begin{staticcontents*}{hdt}% header text next to the image
        \textbf{Aerospace Engineer}
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        
        \large{\textbf{XXX XXXXX XXXX}}
        \vspace{.9\baselineskip}
        
        \textbf{Curriculum Vitae}   
\end{staticcontents*}
% ---------------------------
\begin{staticcontents*}{hdq}% qr-code to the right
    \qrcode[hyperlink,height=0.5in]{http://www.ctan.org}
\end{staticcontents*}

% ~~~ footer contents ~~~~~~~
 \begin{staticcontents*}{ft}
      \begin{center}
      \small{I hereby authorize the processing of the personal data contained in this CV in compliance with the European Regulation (UE) 2016/679.}
      \end{center}
 \end{staticcontents*}

% ~~~ sidebar contents ~~~~~~~
 \begin{staticcontents*}{side}
    \sidehd{About me}
 
    \lipsum[1]\\
 
    \sidehd{Other things}
 
    \lipsum[2] 
 \end{staticcontents*}

% ~~~ normal text content, which goes into the flowframe now ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Here you place text like you would do within a normal textarea, without all those sidebars, headers and footers.\\

Think simple.\\

E.g. use tables for alignment. Use parboxes inside a cell, for example.

\section{You can do this}

And you can do even that:

\subsection{Whatever}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
\hline
A & B\\
better use: & package booktabs\\
image here $\longrightarrow$ & \includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image-a}\\
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image-b}& $\longleftarrow$ image there\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\section{Final}
And if you can't hesitate using minipages: so be it.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @MS-SPO, thanks for your answer. I apologise for the complexity of the code, I forgot to remove some packages/macros that I use for the second page of my CV that I removed from this question for simplicity. Maybe it was better to include the second page as well to give a general overview of my project. Do you think it is better to add it?

Comment: See, it’s always a problem when people reveal what they want step by step, if ever. // Most CVs should fit 1 page. That‘s their purpose. If you need a 2nd page and more, how much do they need to follow the layout from the first page? What do you need to present? // From a HR perspective, ideal candidates are born just for this job, and their CV proves it. Anything else may harm you more than it helps.

Comment: Thank you @MS-SPO, I appreciate a lot your prompts and your new template. Currently, I'm very busy, so I am going to study your code and come back on this topic to propose my customization of it. See you soon...

Answer (score 2):

I propose to define the structure like a `tcbposter` and then write whatever you like inside the corresponding posterbox. You can contol margins like in any `tcolorbox`.

This proposal is only valid for one page curriculum. A tcbposter is not breakable between pages.

Some code to start:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    paperheight=842pt,
    paperwidth=595pt,
    margin=0pt,
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{titleBackColor}{RGB}{25,20,60} %original color: {rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}
\definecolor{sideBarColor}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{mydarkblue}{rgb}{0.07,0.08,0.4}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.4,.4,1}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{245,169,34}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Format of the title section in the side column
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65731
\makeatletter
\def\cv@hrulefill{{\color{titleBackColor}\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1pt\hfill\kern\z@}}
% line before and after text (some tweaking is required here)
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15119
\NewDocumentCommand{\ruleline}{m}{\par\noindent\raisebox{.25\baselineskip}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\cv@hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.25\baselineskip}{\large #1}\hspace{1ex}\cv@hrulefill}}\vspace*{0.05cm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
    poster = {%showframe, 
                    columns=1, rows = 1, spacing=0pt},
    boxes = {sharp corners, valign=top, boxrule=0pt}
]
%Header
\posterbox[colback=titleBackColor, height=2.5cm]{name=headbox, column=1, row=1}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXr}
\tikz[baseline]{\node[circle, minimum width=1.9cm, draw=myyellow, line width=.3mm, path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};}]{};}&
\begin{tabular}{l}
\textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries Aerospace engineer}\\[1mm]
\textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE XXXXXXX XXXXXXX}\\[2mm]
\textcolor{myyellow}{\sffamily\bfseries Curriculum Vitae}
\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{c}
\textcolor{white}{\sffamily Download my CV}\\
\includegraphics[height=12mm]{example-image-b}
\end{tabular}%
\end{tabularx}}

%Footer
\posterbox[colback=titleBackColor!20, height=1cm]{name=bottombox, column=1, above=bottom}{Something on footer}

%Leftcolumn
\posterbox[colback=sideBarColor!25]{name=sidebar, column=1, span=.3, between=headbox and bottombox}{%
\ruleline{\textbf{About me}}
\lipsum[11]
%\begin{tcolorbox}\lipsum[1]\end{tcolorbox}
}

%Rightcolumn
\posterbox[colback=white]{name=mainbox, column*=1, span=.7, below=headbox, between=headbox and bottombox}{}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]