# Line before and after multiple lines of centered text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am looking to add a line around some text. The text may span multiple lines.

I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15119/draw-horizontal-line-left-and-right-of-some-text-a-single-line/15122#15122) that perfectly does this but it is limited to single line and fails when I add a second line.

Single line solutions that were provided in the above link:

1. `\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\hrulefill}}}`
2. `\def\headline#1{\hbox to \hsize{\hrulefill\quad\lower.3em\hbox{#1}\quad\hrulefill}}`

Looking for something like this:

[image: Reference]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\noindent\tikz\draw (0,0)--(\linewidth,0) node[text centered,midway,fill=white,text width=30mm] () {Text\\More text\\and more text};
```

Output:

[image]

**Solved**: Try this code:

```
\noindent\tikz\draw (0,0)--(\linewidth,0) node[align=center,text centered,fill=white,midway] () {Text\\More text\\and more loong text};
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: can 'text width=30mm' be set to variable width such that it adapts to line length?

Comment: @Furqan136 See my edit in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the package `varwidth`

**the code**

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687440/line-before-and-after-multiple-lines-of-centered-text/687442#687442
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
            \centering Text\\More text\\and more loong text
            \end{varwidth}}\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]